# how to declare variable for an excel table using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to declare a variable for my excel table named "Technology Landscape" by entering the below code. Is this correct.

```
TL = Sheet1.ListObjects("TechnologyLandscape").Range.Table
```

Any ideas? Thanks..!

Answer (score 3):

A [ListObject object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247(v=office.11).aspx) is like a range. It needs to be `Set`.

```
Dim TL As ListObject
Set TL = Sheet1.ListObjects("TechnologyLandscape")
Debug.Print TL.ListRows.Count
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped!